# UE4 Grenade deal damage

Tags: arrays, casting, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a grenade BP which the hero throws and wondering how you would set this up ..
I have tried and works fine but this way is caused by a sphere collision and checks what is inside the collision during detonation.

I tried without casting but this didn't work out very well for me, Is there something else I should be doing?

Please ignore the "*get overlapping actors*" class filter, I only done that as a test, i usually leave it blank.

ideally id like to try some sort on line trace when the bomb detonates so it can check if its a direct hit rather than triggering even when safe behind cover.

Any help is **greatly** appreciated, thank you!

[image: Is there casting necessary? say I had 10 other different AI characters, id have to cast throgh them all right?]

[image: I tried without casting but this didn't work out very well for me, Is there something else i should be doing?]

Is there casting necessary? say I had 10 other different AI characters, id have to cast through them all right

I tried without casting but this didn't work out very well for me, Is there something else I should be doing?

Please ignore the "get overlapping actors"class filter, I only done that as a test, i usually leave it blank

Answer (score 0):

I found out using a MultiSphereTraceByChannel works much better.

Comment: Does this answer the question? If not, it should be an edit in the question instead of an answer.